# Selenium to close the window1 and focus on another

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium

I am developing a selenium application in c#. Scenario in my app is like I am browsing to a web page and press a button so that the next window appears.

So,I want selenium to do like this..Once I click the button in my first webpage that browser should be closed and selenium should focus on the next appeared window. How can I achieve that??Any idea on this will be really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look the following link

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html

I hope This will be helpful to you,